# How to hide a cell and remove from flow in objective-C?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using AutoLayout to layout the cells of my tableView. When the content of some elements I have in the cell is empty, I would like to hide the cell.

My issue is that if I flag the cell to be hidden with:

```
cell.hidden = YES;
```

then the "space" used by the cell (whose height is computed in heightForRowAtIndexPath) is still there but grayed out. In effect, the cell is hidden but it's still part of the "flow".

If I try to set the height to zero on the cell I want to hide in the heightForRowAtIndexPath, then I get an exception being raised because auto layout cannot satisfy all the constraints.

Is there a simple way to hide a cell and remove it from the "flow" of the display or do I have to update my constraints on the cell to allow for a height of 0 to achieve that?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your data model to not include the cell, so that it isn't returned in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Alternatively, you could disable auto layout on the cell when you're setting the height to 0:

```
[cell removeConstraints:cell.constraints]
```

Comment: I believe the first one is not the way to go in my case as the number of rows is pre-defined to represent different content fields on an object (like overview, address, street, ...). If one of those fields is empty though, I am trying to hide the cell. 
Your second solution would work (although you'd have to remove the constraints on cell.contentView and not the cell directly). The problem is that I reuse cells so I have to re-update the constraints afterwards. This seems a little messy for something that looks like a pretty simple task.

Comment: You could switch to manual layout for your table cells, or add an `itemIsHidden` property to your data model items, and have `numberOfRowsInSection:` return the number in which that property `== NO`.  Either way, UITableView has no built-in mechanism for hiding table cells that you're telling it to show.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I just tried another way that I like. I modified my constraint to be flexible so moved from: @"V:|-padding-[_titleLabel]-[_descriptionLabel]-padding-|" to: @"V:|-(>=0,<=padding)-[_titleLabel]-(<=padding)-[_descriptionLabel]-(>=0,<=padding)-|".
That way, having a height of 0 is acceptable based on the constraint. Does it sound like a reasonable approach to you?

Comment: That works too, you just lose the built-in padding different between iPhone and iPad.  So you might want to make sure `padding` is slightly larger if you support iPad.  Otherwise it looks like a great solution.